# How to bind mount /sys/kernel/debug with systemd-nspawn?

Tags: virtualization, systemd, mount, containers

`--bind /home` bind mounts `/home`, but `--bind /sys/kernel/debug` only leads to an empty directory. Any other options needed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible. But [the developers are considering to mount /sys as-is](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/27994#issuecomment-1589630976). Which would eliminate the need to `--bind /sys/kernel/debug`.